# Get current element on {{action}} in emberJS

Tags: ember.js, routes, action

Can anyone help me to get the element on emberJS {{action}}?

ex.

```
// application.hbs
<a href="#" {{action 'displayLinks'}}>Get me</a>

// app.js
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
     actions: {
         displayLinks: function() { 
            // returns an object with, no element properties
            console.log(this); 
         }
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// application.hbs
<a href="#" id="elementId" {{action 'displayLinks' 'elementId'}}>Get me</a>

// app.js
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
     actions: {
         displayLinks: function(id) { 
             console.log($("#" + id)[0]);
         }
     }
});
```

Comment: I see. So I just have to get the id passed as parameter on action. Is this possible to trigger some routes from there?

Comment: Yes. But what are you trying to do? If you want to link to another route, just use the link-to helper.